# Create a list that either prints dictionary's value or 0

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list

`lis = [9,4,10,8,2,4]`

I create a dictionary

`dicto = Counter(lis)`

So my dictionary is

`Counter({4: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 2: 1})`

Now I have created another list from 2 (minimum value of the list) to 10 (maximum value of the list)

`lis2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

So I would like to loop through lis2 and check with the dictionary keys and if the dictionary key and lis2 element matches,I store the dictionary key's value else zero.Something like

`[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

So I did something like this

`count = [dicto[i] for i in range(2,11) for j in dicto.keys() if i==j]`

But I am able to get only the values of the dictionary keys which matches with the elements of the lis2 and not the corresponding 0's in case of no match.

How do I get 0's in case of no match?I want to do it in list comprehension style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [get](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
count = [dicto.get(num, 0) for num in list2]
# [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```